# Updating associated record after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Goal:** to update associated model (Listing)

I have successfully (with help from SO) updated my `listing.listing_status` to a certain enum (3) if the listing.orders.count is above a certain threshold.  I now need to update the listing status back to "live" (1) if the threshold is under a certain amount.

**Models:**

```
listing.rb

has_many :orders

order.rb

belongs_to :listings
has_one :order_1
has_one :order_2

order_1.rb

belongs_to :order

order_2.rb

belongs_to :order
```

order_1 and 2 are essentially variables for an order and store different types of files which need their own databases.  When these are created, it then updates the associated Order's order_status to complete with an `@order.update_column(order_status: n)`.

**Issue:** I would be able to do this within my order model like i have with updating when orders are above a certain threshold, but my issue is that... in my order_1 controller in the update method, I update the Order model with an `update_column` which skips callbacks.  So now i need to do this through my order_1 and order_2 controllers (or models), I assume?

In the order_1 controller, I tried:

```
private

def update_listing
  @order_seller = Order.where(order_status: [1]).where(listing_id: Listing.ids)
  # @listing = Order.all.where(params[:listing_id])

  # if @order_seller.count < 999
  #   @listing.update_column(:listing_status, 1)
  # end

  if @order_seller.count <= 999
      @order_seller.listing.update! listing_status: 1
  end

end
```

I receive an error saying the `update_column` method doesn't exist for the commented out section.

With the non-commented out section i get: undefined method listing

How can I update the Listings listing_status once an order_1 is created and the Listings orders are below a certain threshold?

Comment: Sorry.  I changed update_column to update_attribute and it worked.  For whatever reason, this was not working before i created this post but once i restarted my servers, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check also callbacks `after_create`, `after_update` .., and move logic to the model

Comment: I figured it out, should had deleted this but just in case others have a similar issue i kept it up.  i created a comment under my OP about it.  thanks for you answer though